# Function calling in Javascript with double brackets

Tags: javascript

When I call function `hi()()` with double brackets the function displays `hi` output and it will also give error saying, that `hi` is not function.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
<script>

function hello()
{
    document.write("hello");
}
function hi()
{
    document.write("hi");
    return "hello";
}
hi()();
</script>
</html>
```

What is the meaning of using `()()` with function name?

Comment: Please edit the title to specify your question is about double parenthesis, not double brackets.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The double parenthesis would have been useful if `hi` had returned a function instead of its name, like in

```
function hi(){
    return hello;
}
hi()();
```

That's probably what was the intent.

Comment: Or `window[hi()]();` :P

Comment: @Oleg Yes, but that wouldn't make it better.

Answer (score 11):

Putting `()` after something that evaluates to a function will call that function. So, `hi()` calls the function `hi`. Assuming `hi` returns a function then `hi()()` will call that function.
Example:

```
function hi(){
    return function(){return "hello there";};
}

var returnedFunc = hi();  // so returnedFunc equals function(){return "hello there";};
var msg = hi()();         // so msg now has a value of "hello there"
```

If `hi()` doesn't return a function, then `hi()()` will produce an error, similar to having typed something like `"not a function"();` or `1232();`.

Answer (score 10):

()() means calling a function and if returns another function second parenthesis will call it.Please find below example :

```
function add(x){
    return function(y){
        return x+y;
    }
}
```

add(3)(4)

output: 7

in above case add(4) will be called for add function and add(3) will be called for returned function. here value of parameter x is 3 and parameter y is 4.

Please note : we use parenthesis for function call.

Comment: Any idea we can perform dynamic parameter using rest parameter in the same way. I mean add(3)(4) or add(3)(4)(5) or any number of brackets we add it should perform that add operation. How to achieve this ?

Comment: @Santosh that would be done using recursion

Comment: BTW. It can be done by using currying method.

Answer (score 4):

The return value of this function is a string which is not a callable object.

```
function hi()
{
    document.write("hi");
    return "hello"; // <-- returned value
}
```

But if you want to call this function multiple times you can use a for-loop or some things else.

**Example of hi()():**

```
function hi(){
    return function(){ // this anonymous function is a closure for hi function
       alert('some things')
    }
}
```

JS Fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DKCbr/)

If you want to call `hello` function immediately after `hi` try this:

```
 function hi()
    {
        document.write("hi");
        return hello; //<-- no quote needed
        // In this context hello is function object not a string
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval()` to execute it even if it's string :  `eval(hi()+'()');`

Comment: a less evil way of doing the same thing would be `window[hi()]()`