# Multiple brackets function with rest parameter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can we make dynamic [multiple bracket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18802026/function-calling-in-javascript-with-double-brackets) functions.

```
function addThis(x){
   return function(y){
       return x+y;
   }
}

addThis(3)(4) // 7
addThis(3)(4)(5) //12
addThis(3)(4)(5)(6) //18
addThis(1)(1)(1)(1)(1) //5
```

With single bracket function I could achieve something like that using rest parameter.

```
 function add(...args) {
     let sum = 0;
     for(let i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
         sum  = sum + args[i];
     }
     return sum;
 }
```

How can we achieve same with multiple bracket functions.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? (getting **exactly** what you asked for is obviously impossible, because if `addThis(3)(4)` is `7`, then 
`addThis(3)(4)(5)` is `let f=7; f(5)`.)

Comment: You might be looking for "builder pattern".